# Google stacked area chart not working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, stacked-area-chart

I want to accomplish google stacked area chart.

Here is the js fiddle:
[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/)

I also tried adding the options for stacked area:

```
var options_fullStacked = {
          isStacked: 'relative',
          height: 300,
          legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 3},
          vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            ticks: [0, .3, .6, .9, 1]
          }
        };
```

It is available in the documentation for google charts:[stacked area](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#stacking-areas)

I want to display it as shown in this figure:
[image]

Please ignore everything else in this figure except the stacked area chart displayed in between the line chart and the map

Comment: for starters, `isStacked` is boolean -- `true` or `false` -- can't be `'relative'`

Comment: I tried but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to work here, is there more you can share?

see following examples...

**`isStacked: true`**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
        ['2013',  1000,      400],
        ['2014',  1170,      460],
        ['2015',  660,       1120],
        ['2016',  1030,      540]
      ]),
      {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
        vAxis: {minValue: 0}
      }
    );
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**`isStacked: false`**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
        ['2013',  1000,      400],
        ['2014',  1170,      460],
        ['2015',  660,       1120],
        ['2016',  1030,      540]
      ]),
      {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        isStacked: false,
        hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
        vAxis: {minValue: 0}
      }
    );
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```